# dupe_check parameter only works for contacts?

Tags: api, relationships, duplicate-contacts

I would like to disable the dupe check on relationships. Is it true that the API parameter parameter 'dupe_check' works only for contacts or can it be also used in relationship api calls? Here under 4.6.33 'dupe_check'=> 0 does not seem to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dedupe_check works only for contacts.